# Python: Convert Sparse Matrix to Array using a For loop

Tags: python, arrays, sparse-matrix

Using pandas=1.1.5. I created a very large sparse matrix using Bag to Word. I want to convert the sparse matrix to array. But I get
**MemoryError: Unable to allocate 36.6 GiB for an array with shape (17799, 275656) and data type int64**

I don't have admin right to increase the memory in Advanced system settings. So I would like to use a FOR loop to convert the sparse matrix to array. Or is there a better way? Pls assist. Thank you

```
vector1 = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2))  
vector1.fit_transform(text).toarray()
```

**Spare Matrix**
(0, 81346)    1
(0, 89381)    1
(0, 120631)   1
(0, 69446)    1
(0, 8579)     1
(0, 8531)     1
.
.
.
(17798, 72613)        1
(17798, 116023)       1
(17798, 25859)        1
(17798, 206370)       1
(17798, 153517)       1
(17798, 26090)        1

Comment: What is the values range? You can possibly convert the type to use less memory

Comment: @Tom Ron: How do I find the value range of a sparse matrix?

Comment: `vector1.fit_transform(text).shape`

Comment: `A.max()` and  `A.min()`?

Comment: shape: (17799, 275656)

Comment: Can you try to convert to `np.int8` as I suggested you? Does it work?

Comment: Generally, the point of using sparse matrices is to store data that's larger than the amount of memory you'd be able to store/transform. It might be better to think about what you're trying to achieve with the dense matrix and asking a question about that - there may be a better way to do what you're trying to do without converting to a dense matrix.

Comment: @Ryan Pepper: I really need to convert to array as I need to create it into a df where I can add extra columns as features for a machine learning model

Comment: @Ryan Pepper: Do you know how I can slice the sparse matrix and convert it to array part-by-part?

Comment: @Peter You're asking for help doing something that's a bad idea. You should probably ask a question about how to use sparse matrices for your next step instead of this XY question.

Comment: @Peter It doesn't sound to me like what you're trying to do necessitates ditching the sparse matrix structure. If you really *must* go this way, I'd suggest contacting your University (assuming you're working at one) HPC service; they've likely got resources available with large amounts of memory which would be better suited to running this sort of code than a laptop.

Comment: @CJR. I have posted such a Qn before on this forum. But nobody bother to reply, so I deleted the Qn. I can post again and you could reply

Comment: You are most likely to get a response if you ask a clear question and have example data and an example of your expected output.

Comment: @CJR: I have posted the qn now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69670548/random-forest-how-to-add-more-features-to-a-sparse-matrix-and-identify-the-ite

Comment: @Corralien: Can you help with my Qn https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69670548/random-forest-how-to-add-more-features-to-a-sparse-matrix-and-identify-the-ite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
NUM_SPLIT = 2

arr = vector1.fit_transform(text).astype(np.int8)

# Split sparse matrix into NUM_SPLIT small ones
r = range(0, 1+arr.shape[0], arr.shape[0]//NUM_SPLIT)

lst = [arr[i:j] for i, j in zip(r, r[1:])]
```

Output:

```
>>> arr
<4x22 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int8'>'
    with 39 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

>>> lst
[<2x22 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int8'>'
    with 19 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <2x22 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int8'>'
    with 20 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>]
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I still get memory error

Comment: The size is still 36.6 GiB on the error message?

Comment: Can I convert part of the sparse matrix to array instead? How do I slice the sparse matrix? Thanks!

Comment: MemoryError: Unable to allocate 4.57 GiB for an array with shape (17799, 275656) and data type int8

Comment: You have less than 8G of RAM on your computer :)?

Comment: @ Corralien: My laptop has 16.0 GB, but likely the memory allocation in the Advanced System Setting is lower. As said earlier, I can't increase that

Comment: @Peter. Did you have time to test the proposed solution?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't have time to test. But I think it should work. Thanks again!