# Random Forest: How to add more features to a sparse matrix, and identify the items in feature importance?

Tags: python, random-forest

I need to use the features generated by Bag of Words (BOW), and extra features (eg Grp & Rating) in a Random Forest model.

1. As the BOW is a sparse matrix, how do I add the extra features to create a new sparse matrix?  Currently, I convert the sparse matrix to dense and concat the extra features to create a df (eg df 2). Is there a way to add the extra features to the BOW sparse matrix?
2. If we were to use a sparse matrix as the X train, how do I identify the items in feature importance? Currently I use the column of df2.

Thank you

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier


bards_words =["The fool doth think he is wise,",
"man fool"]

vect = CountVectorizer()

bow=vect.fit_transform(bards_words)

vocab=vect.vocabulary_

new_vocab = dict([(value, key) for key, value in vocab.items()])

df0 = pd.DataFrame(bow.toarray())
df0.rename(columns=new_vocab , inplace=True)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Grp': ['3' , '10'],
                   'Rating': ['1', '2']
                   })



df2=pd.concat([df0, df1], axis=1)

X_train=df2.values

forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 500, random_state=0) 
forest = forest.fit(X_train, y_train)
feature_importances = pd.DataFrame(forest.feature_importances_, index = df2.columns, columns=['importance']).sort_values('importance', ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the sparse data structure. Currently you convert a sparse matrix to a dense matrix to a dataframe to another dataframe to a dense matrix. That is not efficient.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from scipy import sparse
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

bards_words =["The fool doth think he is wise,",
"man fool"]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Grp': ['3' , '10'],
                   'Rating': ['1', '2']
                   })

vect = CountVectorizer()
bow=vect.fit_transform(bards_words)

# Stack the two df1 columns onto the left of the sparse matrix
bow = sparse.hstack((sparse.csr_matrix(df1.astype(int).values), bow))

# Keep track of features
features = np.concatenate((df1.columns.values, vect.get_feature_names()))

>>> features
array(['Grp', 'Rating', 'doth', 'fool', 'he', 'is', 'man', 'the', 'think',
       'wise'], dtype=object)

>>> bow.A
array([[ 3,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1],
       [10,  2,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0]])

# Do your random forest
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 500, random_state=0) 
forest = forest.fit(bow, y_train)
feature_importances = pd.DataFrame(forest.feature_importances_, index = features, columns=['importance']).sort_values('importance', ascending=False)
```